# What does 'unix 3 [] STREAM CONNECTED 438037 29037/python' mean?

Tags: networking, netstat

I'm using `netstat` to monitor my Ubuntu server and I've found things as below:

```
tcp     1     0     localhost:48604     localhost:11311     CLOSE WAIT 29511/st   
atic transf 
tcp     0     0     localhost:50810     X86U145:35723       ESTABLISHED 30019/nm 
ea2tfpose 
tcp     0     0     X86U145:42079       localhost:56772     ESTABLISHED 29535/ve    
ctor_map_lo 
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    438037   29071/python
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    478854   29071/python
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    478852   29071/python
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    487641   28978/gksudo
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    436126   28978/gksudo
unix 3     []        STREAM     CONNECTED    473434   28978/gksudo
```

What do these lines mean?
`unix 3 [] STREAM CONNECTED 438037 29037/python`

Comment: Process number 29037 running Python has a connection over a [Unix domain socket](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/unix.7.html) (a socket for local inter-process communication).

Comment: @AlexP  Please make an answer.

Comment: All right, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output of [`netstat -p`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/netstat.8.html)

```
unix 3 [] STREAM CONNECTED 438037 29037/python
```

means that process number 29037 running Python has a connection over a [Unix domain socket](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/unix.7.html) (a socket for local inter-process communication).